# future.then implementation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, future

Does any open-source implementation of `future.then` currently exists?

It would be very useful for a project I am currently working on, and boosts implementation doesn't seem to be there quite yet.

Comment: Do want a pre c++11 solution?

Comment: bamboon: Whatever works in VS2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're developing on Windows with <s>Visual Studio 2012</s> [Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2011/03/09/tasks-and-continuations-available-for-download-today.aspx) and newer, you can leverage the [Parallel Patterns Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx), which offers the [`concurrent::task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750113.aspx) class class which has a similar [`then`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750044.aspx) method.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still stuck in 2010. And I need this for explicit threads (not tasks).

Comment: @CoryNelson; Let me rephrase. I need it for explicit threads, not through a task-scheduler. I'm working with multiple OpenGL contexts and need a good way to synchronize things between them, without blocking.

Comment: The Concurrency Runtime (of which the PPL is a component) is available for use with Visual Studio 2010.  You can get it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd504870%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, but the `concurrency::task` class isn't available in the 2010 version (unless I've misread the documentation.)

Comment: @AdamMaras - The concurrency::task stuff is available as a sample pack for for VS2010: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2011/03/09/tasks-and-continuations-available-for-download-today.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Libprocess has a future implementation with then support, which is embedded in Mesos (http://incubator.apache.org/mesos/) (the path is third_party/libprocess/include/process/future.hpp). The reason I pointed to the embedded version is that it should be the most updated version.

Though I have zero experience using the libprocess library, it looks like working fine as a underlying engine for Mesos.

Drawback:

Only supports Linux platform or Mac platform.